# Synonyms for Words in Python Input During an If/Else Statement

Tags: python

I'm writing a text-based game where I ask the user the turn different directions in python. I'm wanting to set it up so synonyms/variations of the option can be used (such as "Right", or "right", or "r", or "R") but don't want to have to run that in every if/else statement. I've tried making each possible option a variable:

```
left = "Left" or "left" or "l" or "L"
right = "Right" or "right" or "r" or "R"
forward = "Forward" or "forward" "f" or "F"
axe = "Axe" or "axe" or "a" or "A"
sword = "Sword" or "sword"
slingshot = "Slingshot" or "slingshot"
yes = "Yes" or "yes" or "y" or "Y"
no = "No" or "no" or "n" or "N"
```

Then I tried calling it when I put in an if/else statement after an input:

```
def section1():

  #If the person does want to go forward
  def confirm():
    con = input("Are you absolutely sure you want to go this way? ")
    if con == no:
      print("You have gone back")
      time.sleep(0.75)
      section1()
    elif con == yes:
      section1b()
    else:
      print("Sorry I didn't get that")
      time.sleep(0.75)
      confirm()

  direction = input('What way would you like to go? Right, or forward? ')
  if direction == forward:
    print("WARNING! This direction is well known for the great danger that make await where death is inevitable!")
    confirm()
  elif direction == right:
    print("You begin your journey down the creepy corners and dark alleys.")
    time.sleep(1)
    section2()
  else:
    print("That's not an option")
    section1()

    direction = input('What way would you like to go? Right, or forward? ')
    if direction == forward:
        print("WARNING! This direction is well known for the great danger that make await where death is inevitable!")
        confirm()
    elif direction == right:
        print("You begin your journey down the creepy corners and dark alleys.")
        time.sleep(1)
        section2()
    else:
        print("That's not an option")
        section1()
```

Though when I run the code and input "right" or "forward" it goes to the else statement and prints "That's not an option" then loops back. Is there another method to me getting the synonyms (I've tried the same with making the synonyms a list), or is my syntax just not right?

Comment: Your code looks a bit odd. is the function def of confirm is in section1? Why you are calling function confirm recursively(calling inside your own definition)? You are doing same with section1. Where is section2? Please fix the indentation to let us understand what you are trying to do actually.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque The confirm function was just called that to make sure that the user wants to continue to section 1b. Section1b and section2 work similar but were irrelevant to the question for section2 worked just like section1 only that it continued to section3 and had the option of turning left as well. My programme is almost 200 lines long & won't be of any help. I hope that clears it up, I really should have defined that in the question to being with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not work like that. When Python executes the line -

```
left = "Left" or "left" or "l" or "L"
```

It executes the boolean expression `"Left" or "left" or "l" or "L"` and stores its result in `left` , the result of that boolean expression would be `Left` , so `left` then points to the string `"Left"`. It does not delay the evaluation of the boolean expression. Example to show you that -

```
>>> left = "Left" or "left" or "l" or "L"
>>> left
'Left'
```

You should create a set (since you would be searching those sets all the time, and set provide constant time searching ( O(1) )) for each of the `left` ,`right` , etc and use that instead. Example -

```
left = set(["Left","left","l","L"])
right = set(["Right","right","r","R"])
```

Use it using `in` operator -

```
if direction in forward:
```

and

```
elif direction in right:
```

Comment: Sets are underused indeed, good suggestion. I wonder if for small collections (say under 10 elements) if lists are not more efficient; there is no need to hash after all.

Comment: A small experiment on `left` set as well as corresponding `list` showed that list took 92 ns whereas set only took 54.3 ns

Comment: No that didn't work for some reason & still printed out "That's not an option" then looped back to section1(). Thanks for the suggestion, I'll definitely keep that in mind in later projects

Comment: Did you do that for all your `left` , `right`, etc. And change all the `==` checks to `in` ?

Comment: Yeah it did in when I ran it in python's IDLE, I was running it in PyCharm but it wouldn't recognise it so it must be their problem. Thanks heaps!